# How can I compare Likert scale data of two clusters in SPSS?

Tags: clustering, spss, scales, likert

In SPSS, I want to **compare** two clusters of management sciences department faculty members in two universities.

- Which test should I use?
- Can you explain how to do it in SPSS?

Comment: Possible related question: [Group differences on a five point Likert item](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/203/group-differences-on-a-five-point-likert-item).

Answer (score 1):

As chl says, the general issue of what statistical test to use when the dependent variable is a scale based on likert items has been discussed [elsewhere on this site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/203/group-differences-on-a-five-point-likert-item).

For the pragmatic task of running such analyses in SPSS, typing "spss t-test" or "spss Mann-Whitney" into Google will give you many SPSS tutorial options.
Check out for example, some of the following tutorial sites:

- [gsu](http://www2.gsu.edu/~eslnxj/spss/spssmean.html)
- [uofs](http://academic.uofs.edu/department/psych/methods/cannon99/level2b.html)