# How to perform correlation analysis on standardized data?

Tags: correlation, standardization

I am trying to compare a group's performance on a test over the course of three measurements*. Because of the nature of the testing on the 3rd measurement, I cannot directly compare data across all measurements. Therefore, I just standardized my data in SPSS and will now work with the "z-scores"

<sub>* [The grading scale for the test is from 1 to 100 points in the first two measurements, and for the third one is from 1 to 125 (this is an example)]</sub>

I want to see how their performance varies with age, i.e. if there is a correlation between age and performance. However, I **have no clue what kind of correlation analysis I can perform** since as far as I know Pearson's $r$ makes comparisons by making use of z-scores and I have deleted the effect of those.

Comment: You are right, I took it off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [Pearson correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient) may be defined as

$$ r = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n Z^{(X)}_i Z^{(Y)}_i}{n-1} $$

where $Z^{(X)}_i$ and $Z^{(Y)}_i$ are $z$-scores of $X_i$ and $Y_i$, then by converting your variables to $z$-scores you are one step closer to calculating it! See also this answer, as it relates to your question: [Can Spearman's correlation be run on z scores?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13952/can-spearmans-correlation-be-run-on-z-scores/16188#16188)

Comment: Perfect! One extra question actually -  How does one perform a correlation analysis over repeated measures? (or do I post this elsewhere?)

Comment: This sounds like a different question. Check e.g. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44134/correlation-among-repeated-measures-i-need-an-explanation