# How would the correlations change if we normalized the data first?

Tags: correlation, normalization

How would the correlations change if we normalized the data first? ( In Xl miner)

Comment: Can you be precise about how you're normalizing?

Comment: (depending on how exactly normalization is done), there are potential duplicates at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/384188/mean-centering-leads-to-perfect-correlation
 and 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/226283/how-to-perform-correlation-analysis-on-standardized-data

Answer (score 3):

Correlations are invariant to linear transformations of the data - $\text{Cor}(aX+b,cY+d) = \text{Cor}(X,Y)$ - so if your normalization involves only linear transformations of the variables you're calculating the correlation of it will not change sample correlations at all.