# Under what conditions should Likert scales be used as nominal data?

Tags: dataset, likert, categorical-data

Similar to this question, [Under what conditions should Likert scales be used as ordinal or interval data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10/under-what-conditions-should-likert-scales-be-used-as-ordinal-or-interval-data), I am curious under what conditions should/could Likert scales be used as nominal data?

Comment: The only thing I can think of at the moment is when you want to look at things that don't fit into the ordering, like "N/A" answers or even just skipped/missing answers.

Comment: I don't think there's ever a "should", as by definition Likert scales are ordinal and it's never mandatory to ignore that aspect. "could" includes when there is a technique for nominal but not one for ordinal. For example, there are versions of correspondence analysis for ordinal data, but it may be easier to use common or garden versions that assume no more than nominal scale measurement. More generally, using nominal scale and checking whether the ordering is shown in results is sometimes interesting or useful.