# What is an appropriate way to re-scale ordinal features, for cluster analysis? AND any thoughts on euclidean-distance for ordinal data?

Tags: clustering, ordinal-data, likert, scales, hierarchical-clustering

**Background**

I have data from surveys (on political views from [CSES](http://cses.org/)) with answers from respondents in ranking-scales, either 0:10 (0, 1, 2, ..., 10) or 0:3 (0, 1, 2, 3). I want to analyze this data using hierarchical clustering analysis.

To do this I need to scale these features so that they contribute equally to the distance measure. I do not want to weight any feature more relative to the others at the moment, i.e. they should count equally and so need to be scaled.

For similarity measure, I am planning to use Euclidean distance. I am not sure it is appropriate when using ordinal features as in this case. I know that it is also possible to measure similarity with correlation-based measures, but that does not seem appropriate in this case either.

**Questions**

1. Is *standardization* (scaling to mean of 0 and standard deviation of 1) appropriate for scaling the features in this scale, or should I use some other method to scale it?
2. Are there any problems with using Euclidean distance as a similarity measure that I should be aware of in this case?

---

**Additional info**

Some examples of the survey data (the exact formulation used for the questions were  different, I do not have access to that at the moment):

- On a scale 0 to 10 do you dislike or like party X?
- On a scale 0 to 10 do you dislike or like party Y?
- On a scale 0 to 10 where would be on the left-right
- On a scale 0 to 3 do you feel close to a particular party.

Thanks! Have a nice day.

Comment: Nobody forces you to treat your scale as ordinal rather than interval or ratio. I don't see ranking in your example questions. it is rating. So?

Comment: Oh I used the wrong word then. But survey respondents are asked to pick 0, 1,2 ... 10 in the questions.

Comment: The way I see it the scales are ordknal though? I don't know the difference between 0 and 1 on the scale. I don't know if the distance from 0 to 1 is the same  as the distance from 3 to 4 for the same respondent.

Comment: Whether we know something or don't know is a thing we decide ourselves. 1-10 or such fine grained rating scales are often considered interval scale. If you insist the data to remain ordinal you might use Gower similarity. But mind, ranking of ordinal data (done there) is again inventing knowledge from nothing, assuming uniformity of ranks in this instance.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/15313/3277 Gower

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice! I will probably treat it as interval then. But I will have a look at Gower's similarity.

Comment: @ttnphns if I am not mistaken, psychologists have warned to *not* treat them as interval scales, because people don't pick all values. For example, some cultures consider 4 others 7 to be bad luck, and would never choose this.

Comment: C.f. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10/under-what-conditions-should-likert-scales-be-used-as-ordinal-or-interval-data

Comment: @Anony, I agree with your observation, and it is called "focal effect", positive (the figure is liked in the culture) or negative (the figure is disliked). However, this effect is not a _direct_ objection againts intervality or continuality of a scale. Because it pertains to the issue of benchmarks themselves and not the issue of psychometric _distances_ between benchmarks.