# How to handle clustering analysis of data which has different numbers of levels

Tags: clustering, multivariate-analysis, binary-data, ordinal-data

For example, if i have data which is along the lines of

```
variable : levels within variable
x1       : {1,2}
x2       : {1,2}
x3       : {1,2}
x4       : {1,2,3}
x5       : {1,2,3}
x6       : {1,2,3,4,5}
x7       : {1,2,3,4,5}
x8       : {1,2,3,4,5}
x8       : {1,2,3,4,5,6}
x9       : {1,2,3,4,5,6}
x10      : {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
x11      : {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
x12      : {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
```

Where `x1,...,x12` are ordinal variables.

How would one about treating data like the above for clustering? And what sort of algorithms are most typically used?

I'm aware of scaling data for use with some algorithms, but I'm not sure if
scaling data remains valid when there are different numbers of levels as
there are above.

## edit

Following up [this comment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/428919/137921) that says :

> it may or may not be a good idea to try to encode all variables as low/high or low/typical/high based on the value distribution

I'm not too sure what is meant by this.

If I have `x1` with the observations of

```
level  1  :  14   (2.0 %)
level  2  :  788  (98.0 %)
```

What would this mean with respect to encoding all variables as `low/high` based on the value distribution?

Another example might be having `x8` with

```
level  1  :  274 (34.0 %)
level  2  :  264 (33.0 %)
level  3  :  180 (22.0 %)
level  4  :  50  (6.0 %)
level  5  :  10  (1.0 %)
level  6  :  24  (3.0 %)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple method.

Because these values supposedly have some *meaning*, and the correct ways of handling such variables depends a *lot* on what the data meansz and how you *like* to do this.

Assuming this is some questionnaire, it may or may not be a good idea to try to encode all variables as low/high or low/typical/high based on the value distribution, for example.

Comment: thanks - yes this is related to a survey. I've edited the post a little, as I wasn't too sure what you meant by *"try to encode all variables as low/high or low/typical/high based on the value distribution"*. If you're aware of any literature that outlines this that would be appreciated.

Comment: if there are binary variables would this restrict the encoding to low/high across all variables using the approach you've outlined? So I would be encoding all variables to binary variables and working from there? Any links to  literature that discusses this would be appreciated.

Comment: You can find some discussion and literature links here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/10/7828

Comment: yes, thank you. I don't see anything that answers my question about your comment on _low/typical/high_ though. I'm interested in whether this approach would typically consider the variable with the lowest number of levels (binary in this case) to dictate how many others have also. So, all would be coded into low/high in this case. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I don't find it right now, you'll have to search yourself. There was a discussion on the psychologist aspects that values aren't used equally, and shouldn't be considered equally spaced.